# how include module in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have been looking for an answer to this issue for a week.
Hope you can help me:

I am documenting with Sphinx and this is the structure of my project:

```
-folder
    __init__
    -main_tool_folder
        __init__
        main.py
        -docs_folder
    -modulefolder
        __init__
        fileIwanttodocument
```

Inside my main.py

```
sys.path.append('../')
from modulefolder.fileIwanttodocument import functionIneed
```

and the code works

When it comes to Sphinx it fails (gives error on the line where I do the import)

In my conf.py
I use

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath('../../'))
```

and in code.rst

```
.. automodule:: main
   :members

.. automodule:: modulefolder.fileIwanttodocument
   :members:
```

How can I include fileIwanttodocument.py ?
The only way I've found so far is to copy it inside main_tool_folder and this defeats the purpose of creating modules

Comment: What's the explicit error message? I assume that Sphinx is unable to import `modulefolder` because you don't specify it in `conf.py`. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

Comment: File "folder/main_tool_folder/main.py", line 44, in <module>
     from modulefolder.fileIwanttodocument import functionIneed
ImportError: No module named 'modulefolder'

Answer (score 4):

Solved it myself!
in conf.py before

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath('../../'))
```

I had

`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))`

that was causing issues.

apparently the way I am doing is correct!